# Problem with fonts in okular in kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, fonts, evince, okular

I am having a problem with fonts substitutions in kubuntu 20.04 using okular or evince (both). The file has some embedded fonts as in

```
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABCDEE+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no       5  0
Arial                                TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      12  0
Arial,Bold                           TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      14  0
Arial                                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     16  0
Arial,BoldItalic                     TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no      21  0
Arial,BoldItalic                     CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     23  0
Arial,Italic                         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes no  yes     29  0
ABCDEE+Calibri,Italic                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      34  0
ABCDEE+Century Schoolbook,Bold       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes no      36  0
```

an image of how it looks is attached. It seems a problem with fixed width fonts and any help trying to solve it would be appreciated.

[image: rendering]

as you can see the rendering is very poor

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: not really, I managed to make firefox and vivaldi display pdf in a normal way and therefore go around the problem. But okular and so on remain a problem. I am waiting for my next re-install to abandon kubuntu and move to gnome where I never had this kind of problem.